# How can I check if a file is locked by other process?

Tags: bash, shell, unix, flock

I am using Flock to get an exclusive lock on a text file and write something in it, before doing that I want to check if some other process has any kind of lock on that file, if so then I would like to do something else rather be in the queue which is default action in flock.

So, I want something like

```
if locked; then
    do something

else
    ( 
    flock -e 200
    echo "In critical section"
    echo text >> file.txt
    echo text added to File 
    )   200>file.txt
```

is there a way in bash to check this?
I have looked into lsof but I am not able to arrive at solution.

Comment: Your approach is flawed, you have a race condition. Assume your check succeeded, by the time you actually lock the file, it could have been locked by someone else in the mean time. With file I/O you do _not_ check and do, you do and see if it worked.

Comment: @MichaWiedenmann my question is, does there exist a way I can check if the file is locked or not? I get that I have a race condition.

Comment: Yes, as @MichaWiedenmann stated: You **try** to write to the file and **test** whether this worked. If it didn't - the file was locked.

Comment: @StefanM would flock not put that process in queue to get an exclusive lock? Then how would I know if I failed to get the lock in first attempt?

Answer (score 1):

Try using ...

```
( flock -n 200 || exit 1
  echo "In critical section"
  echo text >> file.txt
  echo text added to File 
) 200>file.txt
```

The '-n' flag will prevent blocking, and the exit code will be '1' if the lock was not obtained.

Comment: So instead of exit 1 if I call some function,would work fine or is it something not recommended?

Comment: Probably better to:
if [ $? = 1 ]; then echo 'File was locked'; do_something; fi